# inconsistent div overflow css

Tags: css, html

i recently posted a question regarding problems with div overflows which was solved.

However, my page is now showing some inconsistent behaviour when my div is resized via a checkbox selection which reveals further content.

On the right hand side, the div's (which are floated right) resize and the only other items affected are the ones directly beneath them, which is perfect.

However, the left floated divs, when resized, move the item beneath them over to the right hand side, everything moves out of alignment and huge gaps appear.

Here is the code

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main_content">
        <h1 class="standard">Team Directory</h1>
        <div class="plaque_left">
            <h2>Blackhawks</h2>
            <h3>EB Netball CLub</h3>
            <p>www.random.com</p>
            <p>More text</p>
            <p>and more...</p>
            <p>and more</p>
            <p>finally...</p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="show" id="show"/>
                <label for="show">Named Players</label>
                <article class="small">More content here
                    <br/>
                        <br/>and here
                        <br/>end
                </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



        <div class="plaque_right">
            <h2>Blackhawks</h2>
            <h3>EB Netball CLub</h3>
            <p>www.random.com</p>
            <p>More text</p>
            <p>and more...</p>
            <p>and more</p>
            <p>finally...</p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="show" id="show"/>
                <label for="show">Named Players</label>
                <article class="small">More content here
                    <br/>
                        <br/>and here
                        <br/>end
                </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.plaque_left{ 
display:block ; 
min-height: 23.5em ; 
margin: 1em 1em 1em 5em; 
padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
background: white ; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; 
float:left; width:38% ; 
-webkit-border-radius:10pt}

.plaque_right{
display: block;
min-height: 23.5em ; 
margin:1em 5em 1em 1em ; 
padding: 0 1em 0 1em ;
background: white ; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; 
float: right ; 
width: 38% ;
-webkit-border-radius:10pt}


.plaque_left article {
background:#d0a9f5 ; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10pt ; 
overflow:hidden ;
height: 0px ; 
position: relative ; 
z-index:10; 
-webkit-transition: 
height 0.3s ease-in-out}

.plaque_left input:checked ~ article { 
-webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out}

.plaque_left  input:checked ~ article.small {
height: 140px ; 
position:relative}

.plaque_right article {
background:#d0a9f5 ; 
-webkit-border-radius: 10pt ; 
overflow:hidden ; 
height: 0px ; 
position: relative ; 
z-index:10; 
-webkit-transition: 
height 0.3s ease-in-out}

.plaque_right input:checked ~ article { -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out}
.plaque_right  input:checked ~ article.small {height: 140px ; position:relative}
```

As I said, the right plaque_right divs work fine, but the left don't. Needless to say I am testing in chrome hence the use of -webkit only (will add others in later).

I tried it in js fiddle but the window wasn't wide enough to go into two columns.

Thanks

Comment: you should always add a fiddle to get more help, I made it for you this time:
http://jsfiddle.net/at57C/

Comment: Other then having the same #id twice in the same page, I don't see any problems, left and right column work the same way

Comment: Your divs dont add up, you close the wrapper and maincontent divs after plaque_left, then close 2 non existent divs after plaque_right

Answer (score 0):

What's your chrome version?

At least the code you pasted works fine in 32.0.1700.102.

First two things:

1 two extra div close tag behind the plaque_left. This makes the right panel out of main_content.
  Don't know whether your real code has the same problem.

2 input elements in left panel and right panel have the same name.
  If you click the label in right panel, the article in left panel opens.

I suppose this is only part of your html code.
Maybe the problem is in ~ article.small {height: 140px ; position:relative}

You didn't set the position in article's parent, so this article will not relative to the div.plaque_left.

It will relative to the first parent whose position is not static, which means position is fixed, absolute, or relative, until body.

So, try to add position relative to both plaque divs.